# Set fixed header and footer for html dynamica pages

Tags: html, css

I am creating report, and wanted to print page with header and footer. Number of pages is dynamic. Actually I am printing rows from database, so the number of rows is dynamic, sometimes I have several rows sometimes I have 100 rows. I am trying to create A4 page which will be dynamic, and on each page I will have header and footer.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
  page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
} 
@media screen {
  div.divFooter {
  display: none;
}
div.divHeader {
 display: none;
}
}
@media print {
 div.divFooter {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
}
}
@media print {
  v.divHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
}
</style>
<html>
  <div id="header">
   <img src="../../../img/footer.jpg" > 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
   <img src="../../../img/footer.jpg" > 
  </div>
 </html>
```

This code does not work, does anyone have suggestion? Any help or advice is appreciated?

Comment: I remember running into similar issues with webkit browsers like Chrome not too long ago. I believe this is impossible to do with CSS in those browsers still.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say the images don't show?

If that's the case it's probably the source-path fault, are you opening the `html` file itself or viewing it through an `http` server? Such as `apache`

Comment: Yes I am. I am viewing file through http server apache

Comment: You could try with the absolute path and see if it works out. In that case you should double-check for the relative path and correct it. You can get more info [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)